# Save image in the gallery

Tags: android, image, file, save, gallery

I got a question how to save a bitmap from my App into the android gallery within a Button? I just want that my bitmap is placed in the gallery that the user can use it to set it as maybe his background. So how is it going?

Comment: Probably you should try saving the image in a device location, where the Gallery reads out the images from. For example DCIM or something like that.

Comment: A gallery is an app, not a place. You store images in a place, like [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: Okay and how can I handle it? I tried so many versions but nothing is working for me? It sounds so simple just to save it

Answer (score 1):

You modify the following function to suite your needs

```
 private void takeSnapShot(Bitmap bitmap) {
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    String appName = mContext.getString(R.string.app_name);

    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        String sdroot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String path = sdroot + "/" + appName;
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {
            return;
        }

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", Locale.US);
        String dstr = sdf.format(new Date());
        String filename = path + "/" + dstr + ".jpg";

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LogUtils.println("Exception while writing image");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

        try {
            if (outStream != null)
                outStream.close();
            mMediaScanner.scanMediaByName(filename, R.string.snapshot_save);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } else {
        //  Add some parameters to the image that will be stored in the Image ContentProvider
        int UNIQUE_BUCKET_ID = 111;
        String disp = "anything";

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, disp);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, disp);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, appName + disp);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, appName + " snapshot");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, UNIQUE_BUCKET_ID);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        // Inserting the image meta data inside the content provider
        Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        try {
            if (uri != null) {
                outStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
                if (outStream != null) {
                    outStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            LogUtils.println("Exception while writing image");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save image in gallery like this.

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);

Try like this

The images are displayed in the gallery which are stored on the media store provider

public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

context.getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

}